# Reverse the order of a Doctrine_Collection

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm looking for a clean way to reverse the order of a Doctrine_Collection.
I know it sounds weird, so let me explain my (simple) goal: I need to display the x **latest/newest** record, but I have to display it in the reverse order: the **oldest 1st**, etc.

If it's unclear, here is an example : 
Lets say I have this in my table (lets call it 'example') :

```
id      date
1       2012-01-21
2       2012-03-19
3       2012-02-21
4       2012-03-21
```

So far, I've done this:

```
Doctrine::getTable('Example')->createQuery('d')
    ->orderBy('date DESC')
    ->limit(3);
```

Which returns that

```
id      date
4       2012-03-21
2       2012-03-19
3       2012-02-21
```

But I want that:

```
id      date
3       2012-02-21
2       2012-03-19
4       2012-03-21
```

---

Edit:

I've found a solution to this, using intermediate array & using array_reverse on it. But it doesn't look good :(

Here is the code I've written:

```
    $query = Doctrine::getTable('Example')
            ->createQuery('e')
            ->orderBy('date DESC')
            ->limit(3)
        $collection = $query->execute();

        //Here is the dirty hack:
        $itemArray = array();
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $itemArray[] = $item;
        }
        $itemArray = array_reverse($itemArray);
        $orderedCollection = new Doctrine_Collection($doctrineClass);
        foreach($itemArray as $item) {
            $orderedCollection->add($item);
        }
        //OrderedCollection is OK but... come on! There must be a cleaner way to do it
```

---

Edit 2 : answer from @Adam Kiss

```
        $query = Doctrine::getTable('Example')
            ->createQuery('e')
            ->orderBy('date DESC')
            ->limit(3)
        $collection = $query->execute();

        //Here is the **lovely** hack:
        $orderedCollection = new Doctrine_Collection('Example');
        for ($i=($collection->count() - 1); $i>=0;$i--) {
            $orderedCollection->add($collection->get($i));
        }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Without intermediate array:

```
for ($i = $collection->count(); $i > 0; $i--) {
    $orderedCollection->add($collection->get($i));
}
```

#### Hopefully good answer:

You could export Collection to array and reverse it

```
$query = Doctrine::getTable('Example')
         ->createQuery('e')
         ->orderBy('date DESC')
         ->limit(3)
$collection = $query->execute();
$collection = array_reverse($collection->toArray());
```

#### Old (wrong) answer:

Maybe you should use

```
Doctrine::getTable('Example')->createQuery('d')
  ->orderBy('date ASC')
  ->limit(3);
```

Comment: No, if I do so I won't have the 3 newest records, but the 3 oldest.

Comment: I thought about that too, but the problem is that toArray also convert the Doctrine_Records to arrays... And I definitly don't want that :)

Comment: Congrats, your final solution is the cleaner (to my mind). You just have a small typo on the for loop; $i should go until >0, not >=0

Comment: @haltabush oh yeah, I'll fix that :)

Comment: Oh, and the last minor detail: `->add($collection->get($i);` should be `->add($collection->get($i));`. But asside from that; thanx, it's pretty usefull to me

Comment: Another issue with the `for loop`, is that `count` returns the total number of items and not the last item index. So looping over count will always be `+1` from the last index. eg: `count(['a']) = 1` where the index should be `0`.  So to iterate over all of the available items in the collection in reverse order, it would need to be `$i=$collection->count()-1; $i >= 0; $i--`  [See example](https://3v4l.org/tQPPB) However I suggest utilizing https://stackoverflow.com/a/9842781/1144627 to ensure intended iteration over the keys.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to use any special collection functionality, just iterate over of the elements in reverse order (without any overhead) you can do it pretty easy like this:

```
/** @var $results Doctrine_Collection this is your result collection */
$iterator = $results->getIterator();
$item = end($iterator);

do {
  var_dump($item);
} while ($item = prev($iterator));
```

Comment: That's beautiful :) But, as you can guess, my query is in a model, and I actually want to return a instance of Doctrine_Collection. I'll probably use a mix of your solution and Mahok's (if no one else have a better idea)

Comment: You can return a collection (as the `$results` variable is a collection) and use this in the view (probably in a partial for reusability)...

Comment: True, it's just a bit strange to do that in the view :)

Comment: haltabush is correct, should not being iterating the collection in the view, unless you localize it in the controller then pass it to the view.

Comment: OK, then just do this in your model `return $results->setData(array_reverse($results->getData(), true));`

Comment: @haltabush so what do you think about my last proposal? You can put it in the model and it returns a collection like you would, doesn't it?

Comment: I'll try it on Monday. Thanks!

Comment: I'll use  Adam's solution, I think it's easier to read (at least for me ^^)

Comment: I like this solution more but `prev()` is not implemented in `ArrayIterator` in 2014/2015 (using Doctrine 2.0 ODM). This is because the data is coming as a stream, and is not getting fetched all at once (using the ODM::QueryBuilder with Mongo, not ORM/MySQL).

Answer (score 7):

It seems like you either have to [customize Doctrine_collection](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine/en/latest/en/manual/configuration.html#configure-collection-class) to provide something similar to `array_reverse` within your collection-class or use some hackish approach like the following:

```
$keys = array_reverse($collection->getKeys());
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $object = $collection->get($key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, surely just remove "DESC" from the orderby. The query returns in date descending order exactly as it's told and you want it in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use like this

```
     ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
```

because in this documentation 
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html
orderby's signature requires ASC/DESC as second parameter

```
      public function orderBy($sort = null, $order = null);
```

Comment: Well, yes, but it's not a big deal anyway. I've always used is this way, it works too; it's also less confusing when you have multiple orderBy clauses

Comment: i see... if you dont mind using raw sql with doctrine this might help SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM  `Example` 
ORDER BY DATE DESC 
LIMIT 3
)foo
ORDER BY 2 ASC

Comment: I do mind about raw sql, sorry :) I thought about that too. By the way, the accepted answer is OK for me. I just forgot to end the bounty (I thought it was automatic)

Answer (score 0):

If you want an `ArrayCollection` object, another solution to this which expands on the answer given by @adam-kiss is to use the returned value of `array_reverse` to construct a new `ArrayCollection` object which reduces the need of a `for` loop.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

$query = Doctrine::getTable('Example')
    ->createQuery('e')
    ->orderBy('date DESC')
    ->limit(3)
;
$collection = $query->execute();
$orderedCollection = new ArrayCollection(array_reverse($collection->toArray()));
```

Comment: I wanted a Doctrine_Collection. Maybe I can give it an ArrayCollection as a setter, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

### For Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection

```
/** @var Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection $posts */
$posts = $category->getPosts();
for ($i = $posts->count()-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $post = $posts->offsetGet($i);
    // ... do some logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me.
doctrine version: 1.2

```
    $collection = //make doctrine collection;
    $reversed_array = array_reverse($collection->toArray());
    $collection->fromArray($reversed_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
...

$criteria = Criteria::create();
$criteria->orderBy(['id' => 'DESC']);

return $this->objections->matching($criteria);
```